# How to do an out of source build with scons?

Tags: scons, out-of-source

I have been using cmake to build my projects out of source, which is really convenient as you avoid polluting your source directory with unnecessary files.

Assuming the CMakeLists.txt is in the current directory, this could be done as follows:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

How can I do the same in scons?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720142/how-to-force-scons-output-exe-obj-lib-dll-to-specific-build-directory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `SConstruct` file, you use a variant dir:

```
SConscript("main.scons", variant_dir="build", duplicate=0)
```

Then in `main.scons` you set up everything as usual:

```
env = Environment()
env.Program(target='foo', source=Split('foo.c bar.c'))
```

It's possible to do this without hardcoding the variant dir into the SConstruct by (ab)using repositories, but that approach has its bugs. For the record, you would run the above as follows to build in another directory:

```
mkdir mybuild
cd mybuild
scons -Y .. -f ../main.scons
```

The easiest and most workable is to just use `variant_dir`. You then run this as usual from the top level source directory. All the build artefacts get produced in the `build` sub directory.

In response to [JesperE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13051/jespere)'s comment, here is how you could write the top level SConstruct to add an optionally named build directory:

```
AddOption('--build', default='build')
SConscript("main.scons", variant_dir=GetOption('build'), duplicate=0)
```

Then you would call this from the command line as follows, to create a build directory called "baz":

```
$ scons --build=baz
```

Comment: But can't you just pass the value of the `variant_dir` parameter as a command-line argument to avoid hardcoding it?

Comment: You can, but you have to remember to pass it to the `scons` command line each time.

Comment: You could set `variant_dir=GetLaunchDir()` to get CMake-like behaviour: put build outputs in the directory where `scons` was run from. Source of this idea: https://github.com/memsharded/conan-scons-template/blob/master/src/SConstruct