# SCons Output in Build directory

Tags: scons

I'm trying to modify my SCons files so that they put the **generated** files into a *build* directory. Initially I though *VariantDir* could be an option but judging from all I read and the examples it does not do what I want.

Is there any easy way to force SCons to put the output in a certain directory without having to rewrite all the sources and scripts?

Comment: What's the problem with `VariantDir`? Did you try using `duplicate=0`?

Comment: For use of `VariantDir` you have to sell your whole soul. Which means you either have to do everything in the `VariantDir` or nothing. The thing I and a lot of others want is to put only **generated** stuff into the build dir and not everything.

Comment: Isn't that what `duplicate=0` does? From the docs:

Duplicating the source tree may be disabled by setting the duplicate argument to 0 (zero). This will cause scons to invoke Builders using the path names of source files in src_dir and the path names of derived files within variant_dir.

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with VariantDir for a while (it wasn't doing anything at all), I ended up using `variant_dir` parameter in the top level SConscript call, which causes all downstream build outputs end up in a parallel 'build' tree:
`SConscript(['subdirs/SConscript'], variant_dir='build', duplicate=0)`
My build structure is a hierarchy of SConscripts in subdirs/sub-subdirs, etc. With this call the outputs end up in build/sub-subdirs at the same level as they would in the source.

This eats up one level, though (subdirs), and using "../build" does not help. The solution is to have a SConscript file at the same level as SConstruct and call `SConscript(['SConscript'], variant_dir='build', duplicate=0)`

See also [Force Scons output (exe, obj, lib & dll) to specific build directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720142/force-scons-output-exe-obj-lib-dll-to-specific-build-directory) - it has a similar answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `VariantDir` with `duplicate=0` should work.

Comment: This would require me to rewrite the majority of build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Facing similar frustration, I added a site_scons that added replacement builders (e.g. "Exe" instead of "Program") and specified an emitter for that builder that replaced the path portion with the build directory.  This requires the use of the alternate builder throughout your SConscripts though.

Alternatively you could try to subclass Environment and rewrite the main targets to use target rewrites.  Then you specify your Environment as the default (modifying Scons.Script.DefaultEnvironment or something like that).  This approach kept the SConscripts static but got very messy and requires more maintenance over time as scons internals change.

Answer (score 0):

You might use Install or InstallAs on target output. It works for me.

```
lib = env.SharedLibrary(target = "some_target", source = sources);
env.InstallAs( target = "folder/output_name.ext", source = lib );
```